# Why do the lattice points of these ellipses obey a curious relationship?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, conic-sections

Starting with,

$$x^3+y^3+z^3 = (z+1)^3$$

we do the substitution $z = 3 n^2x + (3 n^2 + 1)(y - 1)$ like Adam Bailey in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4830509/4781) to get the *ellipse*,

$$x^2 - x y + y^2 - (27 n^4 - 1) x - (27n^4 + 18 n^2 + 2 ) y + (27n^4 + 9 n^2 + 1 ) = 0$$

after removing a trivial factor. For general integer $n$, this family of ellipses seems to have ***nice*** properties. The case $n=1$ was in the linked post. For $n=2$,

$$x^2  - x y + y^2 - 431 x - 506 y + 469 = 0$$

which yields the ellipse,

[image]

graphed by the [Desmos calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator). Using the $6$ blue lattice points (and flipping $x,y$ as needed), we get the nice $6$-cycle of equalities,

\begin{align} \color{blue}{(-66)}^3\; +\; \color{blue}{97}^3 + 456^3 &= 457^3\\
 \color{blue}{97}^3\; +\; \color{blue}{594}^3 + 8376^3 &= 8377^3\\    
 \color{blue}{594}^3 + \color{blue}{1003}^3 + 20154^3 &= 20155^3\\ 
 \color{blue}{1003}^3 + \color{blue}{840}^3 + 23106^3 &= 23107^3\\ 
 \color{blue}{840}^3 + \color{blue}{343}^3 + 14526^3 &= 14527^3\\
 \color{blue}{343}^3 + (-66)^3 + 3654^3 &= 3655^3\end{align}

thus the sextuple $a_i = (-66, 97, 594, 1003, 840, 343)$ and similarly for the given $24$ lattice points. But the [Alpertron calculator](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM) says this ellipse has a total of $48$, with the others being,

[image]

So we in fact have $48/6 = 8$ sextuples,

\begin{align}a_i & = (-66, 97, 594, 1003, 840, 343)\\ 
b_i & = (-72, 115, 618, 1009, 822, 319)\\ 
c_i & = (90, -47, 294, 847, 984, 643)\\ 
d_i & = (72, -41, 318, 865, 978, 619)\\
e_i & = (-78, 139, 648, 1015, 798, 289)\\ 
f_i & = (264, 823, 990, 673, 114, -53)\\  
g_i & = (-42, 49, 522, 979, 888, 415)\\  
h_i & = (24, -17, 390, 913, 954, 547)\end{align}

each one yielding a sextuple system $x^3+y^3+z^3 =(z+1)^3$ as demonstrated above for $a_i$. But notice the curious relationship,

$$\alpha = a_1 + a_3 + a_5 = b_1 + b_3 + b_5 = \dots = h_1 + h_3 + h_5 = 1368$$

$$\beta = a_2 + a_4 + a_6 = b_2 + b_4 + b_6 = \dots = h_2 + h_4 + h_6 = 1443$$

---

**Question**: Using the theory of conic sections, what is the geometric interpretation of \begin{align}\alpha &= 3(27n^4+6n^2)\\ \beta &= 3(27n^4+12n^2+1)\end{align} and why is it invariant using *different* lattice points?

**P.S.** For this family, I've tested it with other $n$ and the same relationship seems to hold.

---

**Addendum**: As Jan-Magnus pointed out in his answer $\big(\dfrac{\alpha}3,\dfrac{\beta}3\big)$ should be the *center of the ellipse*. So,

\begin{align}
\alpha &= a_1 + a_3 + a_5 = -66 + 594 + 840 = 1368 = 3\times456\\
\beta &= a_2 + a_4 + a_6 = \;97 + 1003 + 343 = 1443 = 3\times481\end{align}

Yup, looks like $(456,481)$ is indeed the center.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems they average to the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the center of the ellipse which is $$(x,y)=(27n^4+6n^2,27n^4+12n^2+1)=(\frac{\alpha}3,\frac{\beta}3),$$ as you can find by solving $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2 - x y + y^2 - (27 n^4 - 1) x - (27n^4 + 18 n^2 + 2 ) y + (27n^4 + 9 n^2 + 1 )) = 0\\\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2 - x y + y^2 - (27 n^4 - 1) x - (27n^4 + 18 n^2 + 2 ) y + (27n^4 + 9 n^2 + 1 )) = 0.$$

---

**Edit**: If translated to the center (by Jan-Magnus Økland):

Let $x\to x+\dfrac{\alpha}3,\; y\to y+\dfrac{\beta}3$, then,

$$x^2-xy+y^2=9n^2(3n^2+1)(27n^4+9n^2+1)$$

**Edit:** (More important given the solution for the [other Q](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845639/what-is-the-relation-between-these-pairs-of-triangles-on-an-ellipse-for-x3y3).)

Written about the center and multiplied by two, the equation is $$2(x-3n^2(9n^2+2))^2-2(x-3n^2(9n^2+2))(y-(3n^2+1)(9n^2+1))+2(y-(3n^2+1)(9n^2+1))^2=\\18n^2(3n^2+1)(27n^4+9n^2+1)$$ and the Smith normal form is  $$\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\ 0&3&0
\\ 0&0&-3M \end {array} \right] =\\
 \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&1&0\\ 1&2&0
\\ M & 2M &1\end {array}
 \right] \cdot
 \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 2&-1&0\\ -1&2&0
\\ 0&0&-3M \end {array} \right] 
 \cdot \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&-1&0\\ 0&1&0
\\ 0&1&1\end {array} \right] $$

where $M = 6n^2(3n^2+1)(27n^4+9n^2+1).$

[image]

Comment: Ah, I understand how you did it. We get the partial derivatives [using Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=partial+derivative+of+%28x%5E2+-+x+y+%2B+y%5E2+-+%2827+n%5E4+-+1%29+x+-+%2827n%5E4+%2B+18+n%5E2+%2B+2+%29+y+%2B+%2827n%5E4+%2B+9+n%5E2+%2B+1+%29%29+wrt+to+x) so \begin{align}
-27n^4 + 2x - y + 1 &= 0\\ 
-27n^4 - 18n^2 - x + 2y - 2 &= 0
\end{align} thus 
\begin{align}
x &= 27n^4+6n^2 = \frac{\alpha}3\\
y &= 27n^4+12n^2+1 = \frac{\beta}3
\end{align} But what led you to the idea of using partial derivatives?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII It’s the standard way to find the center of an ellipse or a hyperbola.

Comment: I see. Let me refine my question. What was your clue that $(\alpha, \beta)$ would involve the center of the ellipse?

Comment: Actually it finds for a hyperbola where the asymptotes cross or for an ellipse where the only real point is (where the imaginary lines cross) because the equation is a constant added from the equation for those cases anyway

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Honestly, it was the first thing I tried, because it’s the first thing you do in searching for the canonical form.

Comment: I added a third image showing $(\alpha/3,\,\beta/3)$. It seems to be at the center indeed. **P.S.** For this family of ellipses, one can calculate the center from 3 carefully chosen lattice points. I wonder if it is possible to do the same for this ellipse [with 11 lattice points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69313/what-is-the-simplest-ellipse-that-goes-through-exactly-13-lattice-points).

Comment: I made a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845639/what-is-the-relation-between-these-pairs-of-lattice-point-triplets-on-an-ellipse) about how I found $(\alpha, \beta)$ without knowing about the partial derivatives method. Might be of interest.

Comment: What was the transformation you did on $(x,y)$ to move the center of the family to the origin $(0,0)$?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII On the equation you have to use the inverse translation $x\to (x+x(S)), y \to (y+y(S)).$

Comment: I understand it now. Your transformation was $x\to x+\dfrac{\alpha}3,\,y\to y+\dfrac{\beta}3$. But to maintain the Diophantine $x^3+y^3+z^3=(z+1)^3$ relation, one has to reverse the transformation.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII See the edit

Comment: I tweaked your edit to make it more aesthetic, and added your pic. I hope it is ok.

Comment: You made a transformation such that the center of the ellipse coincides with the origin $(0,0)$. Is there any general transformation such that the vertices of triangle ADE and triangle BCF will coincide?

Comment: A little remark about the triangular correspondences in the last figure : they can be "rendered" by the $2 \times 2$ matrix $A:=\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&-1}$ with order $3$ ($A^3=I_2$), explaining the 3-cycles, for example $\pmatrix{366&162&-528&366&162&-528\\
-162&528&-366&-162&528&-366}$ where each column is the image of the previous one by $A$ : $\pmatrix{366\\-162} \stackrel{A}{\rightarrow} \pmatrix{162\\528} \stackrel{A}{\rightarrow}...$

Comment: [Ctd] which doesn't come as a surprise because if we denote by $Q=\pmatrix{1&−1/2\\−1/2&1}$ the matrix of the quadratic form $x^2−xy+y^2$, we have $A^TQA=Q$ : this matrix $A$ preserves the quadratic form (in other terms, $A$ belongs to the orthogonal group associated with $Q$).

Comment: Any comment about my remarks ?